# Composer не ставит пакеты

Tags: php, composer

Всем привет.
Не работает `composer install`.

Версия `Composer version 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17`

'composer update` делал

В чём может быть проблема?

Лог ошибки:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for graphaware/neo4j-bolt 1.4.2 -> satisfiable by graphaware/neo4j-bolt[1.4.2].
    - graphaware/neo4j-bolt 1.4.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for php-gcm/php-gcm 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by php-gcm/php-gcm[1.1.1].
    - php-gcm/php-gcm 1.1.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - graphaware/neo4j-bolt 1.4.2 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
    - graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0 requires graphaware/neo4j-bolt ^1.0 -> satisfiable by graphaware/neo4j-bolt[1.4.2].
    - Installation request for graphaware/neo4j-php-client 4.0.0 -> satisfiable by graphaware/neo4j-php-client[4.0.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Файл composer.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "core/vendors"
  },
  "require": {
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "justinrainbow/json-schema": "~2.0",
    "php-gcm/php-gcm": "^1.1.1",
    "paragraph1/php-fcm": "^0.7.0",
    "prewk/xml-streamer": "^0.5.0",
    "nicolab/php-ftp-client": "^1.3",
    "matthiasmullie/minify": "^1.3",
    "matthiasmullie/path-converter": "^1.0",
    "graphaware/neo4j-php-client": "4.0",
    "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.8.1",
    "gregwar/captcha": "1.*",
    "smarty/smarty": "~3.1",
    "pear/cache_lite": "1.8.0",
    "pear/log": "1.13.1",
    "google/apiclient": "1.1.5",
    "adyen/php-api-library": "1.2",
    "pear/mail": "1.4.1",
    "pear/mail_mime": "1.10.1",
    "pear/net_smtp": "1.7.3",
    "pear/auth_sasl": "1.1.0",
    "ryanwinchester/hubspot-php":"~1.0",
    "spheremall/ms-client": "~1.0.28"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "6.2"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SM\\": [
        "custom/framework",
        "core/framework"
      ]
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "SM\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: написано же вам 3 проблемы. установите/включите требуемые расширения пхп (curl, bcmath)

Comment: 2 проблемы, отсутствие curl и bcmath в php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl php-bcmath
```